# MySQL, How get from query (who use LIMIT) number of returned rows and save rowset. (Store procedure / function) and by number of rowset statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count, rowset

For example Table x have 9 records

x = 5

I make query:

```
 Select * From `x` LIMIT 0,5
```

// I need data from this query and rowset count.

// Variable count -- Stores the number of rows  returned by first query,

When first query rowset is smaller than 5 rows, then

I make new query from table z

```
  Select * From `z` Limit 0,(5 - count)

  --------------------------------
```

Trick by FOUND_ROWS not working.

http://pastebin.com/1kKD0wqC

```
  --------------------------------
```

Problems:

How to do it in Store procedure / function (MySQL)?

How get from first query (rowset and number of returned rows) in one query?

```
  --------------------------------
```

Targets:

After work function should return

Sum of rowset (query 1 and 2).

Or

rowset query 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found solution:

MySQL (Content of Store Procedure):

```
Set @tmp = 0;
Select `field_1`, `field_2` From `table_1` Where @tmp := @tmp + 1 LIMIT 0 ,5;
```

// We have row set and in session variable (@tmp) - number of returned rows

---

@TIP

```
 @tmp := @tmp + 1
```

It's Must be before all conditions in where.

For example:

```
[.....] Where @tmp := @tmp + 1 And `field_2` > 1 LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Will return always 1...

---

Correct Version

```
[.....] Where `field_2` > 1 And  [Other conditions] And @tmp := @tmp + 1  LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From `z` Limit 0,(5 - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `x` LIMIT 0,5))
```

Didn't check if it works but it sholud. I refer to the manual:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: This variant not give me a

a SUM of first query rowset and second query rowset

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html Do you mean anything like this?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0UePTBbm

It's not it.
I need it ( 3 rows in set (0.00 sec) ) and rowset :)